# Article Shows as white screen but plugins load

Tags: articles

I have an article which shows as published in my back end.

If I click on "preview" which I believe is Regular Labs "better preview" I see a screen saying the article is unpublished.

I also have a menu item linked to it and published.  Visiting that URl gives me a black screen.  Google Tag Manager and JCH Optimize are loaded though.  As well as a the body tag/element.

This seems to be the case with all new articles.  Here is an example so you can view the source code:

https://www.squareballoon.co.uk/microservices/local-seo-directory-submission-1-off-payment-179

I have tried disabling my Litespeed cache plugin in "extensions" "manage" but that didn't help.

[image]

[image: Preview says article is unpublished]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I followed various other articles on the internet that suggested various good fixes mine was caused by something different.  I include the other articles for completeness.

**My Solution:**

I had 1 template set to the default template, but I had assigned another template to all pages which caused me this problem.

I think my situation was unusual so I include the other information to help anyone else who arrives here.

**More common solutions:**

from: https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla/white-screen-of-death/

> Option #1. Change Error Reporting to Maximum
>
> set error reporting to maximum
>
> Try to log into your Joomla administrator area. If you can get in, go
>   to Global Configuration > Server > Error Reporting and set it to
>   Maximum. You can find a more detailed tutorial for this here. Now
>   check the front of your site to see if any errors are displaying. If
>   you can't access your site's administrator area, set this in your
>   configuration.php file:
>
> public $error_reporting = 'development';
>
> Option #2. Edit Files in FTP
>
> Log in to your Joomla site files via FTP. Find your index.php file
>   located in the root of your site. Open the index.php and add this code
>   directly after the very first line of the file:
>
> ini_set('display_errors', TRUE); error_reporting(E_ALL);
>
> Option #3. Edit PHP.ini file
>
> The PHP.ini file is a vitally important file that controls many of
>   your server's settings. If you don't know where it is, use this
>   tutorial to find it.
>
> We recommend that you change these two settings:
>
> Set Display error to On:
>
> display_errors = On
>
> Set error reporting:
>
> error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
>
> Option #4. Check Your Server Log
>
> Check your server error log for any indication of what is causing the
>   issue.
>
> Check your Joomla server log
>
> If you are not sure how to access this, you can contact your hosting
>   company.
>
> If you are on localhost, you can usually find it in a directory called
>   "logs" within the installation folder of your local server. You've
>   found the error message. Now what?
>
> When you have discovered what is causing the error message, it's time
>   to analyze it. You will hopefully see errors that resemble those in
>   the image below.
>
> Even if you don't understand the message, you know which extension is
>   causing problems
>
> In these examples, the errors come from sh404SEF and from Xmap. Even
>   if you don't understand the message, you know which extension is
>   causing problems.
>
> If the name of an extension can't be found, you might see an error
>   message like the ones below. This may mean that there's a problem with
>   the Joomla core files.
>
> What can you do now that you've identified the troublesome extension?
>
> What can you do now that you've identified the troublesome extension?
>   Problems with an extension? Disable the extension
>
> This tutorial shows how to disable a plugin, but applies to other
>   types of extensions also.
>
> The quickest and easiest solution is to log in to your site via FTP.
>
> If the troublesome extension is a component, go to the /components/
>   folder and change the name of the extension folder.
>
> For example, change /com_sh404SEF/ to /com_sh404SEF_disabled/.
>
> You may also need to change the directory name within the component in
>   the /administrator/components/ directory as well. Problems with the
>   Joomla core? Reupload the core files
>
> If you didn't install any extensions and you think it may be caused by
>   the core Joomla files, try reinstalling all of Joomla core files.
>
> You can do this by downloading the latest version found on joomla.org
>   and overwriting all the directories to your servers FTP.
>
> If you have access to the administrator area, you can also try Step 5
>   from this tutorial.